# Cannot get Razor intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Having done everything I have found I still cannot get Razor Intellisense to work in Razor views.

I have several squiggles in the web.config file in the Views folder.  I have a reference to System.Web.Webpages.Razor in my project but the web.config file still cannot resolve the 3 references in configSections and the error for WebViewPage says it must be convertible to System.Web.UI.Page

What to try next?

Comment: You have Visual Studio 2010 SP 1 installed?

Comment: Make sure you have MVC 3 installed with the tools update (or the jan release). Also make sure your project has a Web.Config within the Views directory.

Comment: If u even have Visual Studio 2010 without sp1 you will have intellisense.

Comment: I've heard of people having issues with reshaper and razor intellisense.  If you are using resharper you could try changing intelllisense to use vs rather than resharper.  See if it is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that there was still a remnant of MVC2 left on my computer. Uninstall did not completely remove it and the couple of files left stopped the new MVC 3 installation from completing correctly.  I apologize for not having the url handy, but someone blogged on this subject and gives you a step-by-step how to.  I had to do even more than what he suggested, but that was the solution...to clean every last remnant of MVC 2 or MVC 3 CTP from your computer